# How to disable a border of html?

Tags: css, border

Can any one please tell me how can I disable the border of html? I was going to embed the html on another application and the border makes it look kind of boring.. Is there any CSS code to do this?

Comment: Maybe some screenshots or something? "The border around the HTML" is very vague...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using an `iframe`. If so:

[Remove border from IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034/remove-border-from-iframe)

Comment: No it is not an iframe, it is the main border of the html window.

Comment: HTML doesn't have an inherent border. What application are you embedding a website into? What language is it coded in?

Comment: I am using Auto play media studio, if you are aware of it. It imports an html web file in your project but it is unable to hide the borders.

Comment: See, don't you think that would've been useful information for us to have? Looks like it's a GUI app, so if you don't see an option to tweak it, you probably *can't* tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `border-style:none` in CSS, but it would help if you clarified your question a bit :-).

Comment: yea making the border style none is what I need, How do I do that?

Comment: My question is simply how to hide the main border of an html. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, your question is a bit unclear. I will try my best.

If you are talking about an iframe, try this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.whatever.com/" frameborder="0">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_frameborder.asp

*Actually in this example `frameborder="yes/no"` also works in IE.

The previous example is deprecated in HTML5, so I would recommend using the following CSS code (or if you aren't using an iframe):

```
frame-border: none;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

`border: 0;` might also work, but I haven't tested it yet.