# HTML5 and frameborder

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I have an iframe on an HTML5 document. when I validate I am getting an error telling me that the attribute on the `iframe frameBorder` is obsolete and to use CSS instead.

I have this attribute **`frameBorder="0"`** here because it was the only way I could figure out how to get rid of the border in IE, I tried `border:none;` in CSS with no luck. Is there a compliant way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> <s>HTML 5 doesn't support attributes such as frameborder, scrolling, marginwidth, and marginheight (which were supported in HTML 4.01). Instead, the HTML 5 specification has introduced the seamless attribute. The seamless  attribute allows the inline frame to appear as though it is being rendered as part of the containing document. For example, borders and scrollbars will not appear.</s>

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Deprecated_attributes)

> `frameborder` **Obsolete since HTML5**
>
> The value `1` (the default) draws a border around this frame. The value `0` removes the border around this frame, but you should instead use the CSS property border to control  borders.

Like the quote above says, you **should** remove the border with CSS;
either inline (`style="border: none;"`) or in your stylesheet (`iframe { border: none; }`).

That being said, there doesn't seem to be a single iframe provider that doesn't use `frameborder="0"`. Even YouTube still uses the attribute and doesn't even provide a style attribute to make iframes backwards compatible for when frameborder isn't supported anymore. It's safe to say that the attribute isn't going anywhere soon. This leaves you with 3 options:

1. Keep using `frameborder`, just to be sure it works (for now)
2. Use CSS, to do the "right" thing
3. Use both. Although this doesn't resolve the incompatibility problem (just like option 1), it does and will work in every browser that has been and will be

As for the previous state of this decade-old answer:

The `seamless` attribute has been supported for such a short time (or not at all by some browsers), that MDN doesn't even list it as a deprecated feature. Don't use it and don't get confused by the comments below.

Comment: So is there a way to produce frameBorder=0 in CSS?

Comment: That's really annoying, I'm using the latest Chrome and it just doesnt work. Although frameborder="0" does.

Comment: revisiting this, seamless does work on chrome ff and safari. Put it in the iframe like so : <iframe seamless

Comment: Gotta disagree with @RGBK.  In my testing, neither IE 9, FF 5, Chrome 12, nor Safari 5 (on Win 7) support the seamless attribute.  See this test page for more info:  http://maxdesign.com.au/jobs/seamless/

Comment: "The seamless attribute is currently not supported in any of the major browsers." - http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_seamless.asp

Comment: `seamless` is not functionally equivalent to `frameBorder=0`. For example, the CSS from the containing page can cascade into the `iframe` itself, and links open in the context of the child page.

Comment: Your supposed to use `border-width: 0px;`, but I'm afraid that this is not cross-browser compatible either for use with `iframes`.  `seamless` is still not supported by all browsers!  This is one of those few HTML5 issues that you just have to accept.  Use `frameborder="0"` and the hell with the validation!

Comment: Thanks Solomon, nice to see one of the original IE6 devs enter the discussion :p

Comment: It is incorrect and misleading to say that this or that specification does or does not “support” some HTML feature. Browsers support things. Besides, HTML5 describes the attributes mentioned (earlier HTML specs do not describe all of them) and *encourages* browsers to support them (while declaring them as non-conforming, but this is a requirement on *documents*, not browsers).

Comment: `seamless` has been removed from the HTML5 spec, so there will never be support for it. [@ForTheWatch's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10831379/1079573) is now the best.

Answer (score 52):

As per the other posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985658/ie-frameborder-alternative), the best solution is to use the CSS entry of

```
style="border:0;"
```

Comment: I think they recommend:  `border-width: 0px` TBH.  `border: none;` will NOT work.

Comment: @solomon, why are you saying `border: none;` wont work? It works on firefox and chrome (which is webkit so thats safari and soon to be opera)

Comment: @cnotethegr8 - It doesn't work in IE and Opera (current version), haven't tested in Chrome, Safari, and/or Firefox.  I test for the crappy browsers, because if it works in them, than it is almost sure to work in the others.

Comment: @SolomonClosson `I test for the crappy browsers, because if it works in them, than it is almost sure to work in the others.` My god that naïve. If you want to make sure your app works in a browser you have to test in *that* browser, plain and simple. There are no guarantees, only quirks.

Comment: Quick note is that the unit in 0px is redundant. I prefer margin: 0; or border: 0; because 0px == 0em == 0% == 0 when it comes to CSS.

Comment: Now that `seamless` has been dropped from the spec this is the only correct answer

Answer (score 18):

Since the `frameborder` attribute is only necessary for IE, there is another way to get around the validator. This is a lightweight way that doesn't require Javascript or any DOM manipulation.

```html
<!--[if IE]>
   <iframe src="source" frameborder="0">?</iframe>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
   <iframe src="source" style="border:none">?</iframe>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is the best answer to the question asked. However, the *goal* of compliance to HTML5 (which is work in progress and may and will change without notice) is not useful, especially when it makes you use tricks that do not serve any other purpose than such compliance and that make the code more complicated. It is best to keep using `frameBorder="0"` if you don’t want a border around an inline frame.

Comment: Absolutely true. Just want to note that as the frameborder attr is purely presentational, there is not much chance that it will ever return to the HTML standard, no matter how much the standard is changing.

Comment: The attribute *is* in the HTML5 “standard”: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#frames-and-framesets

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Wait, what? Then why would the OP get a validation error? Oh, sorry, the page you link to is about `frame` and `frameset`, not `iframe`. The attribute ___is___ obsolete on the `iframe` element; see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-iframe-frameborder

Comment: The validation error is issued because the feature is declared obsolete, which really does not mean much more than issuing the message. The attribute is still *defined* in HTML5 and browsers are expected, according to HTML5 CR, to keep supporting it.

Answer (score 6):

This works

```
iframe{
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the same for technique for "fooling" the validator with Javascript by sticking a target attribute in XHTML `<a onclick="this.target='_blank'">`?

- *onsomething* = " this.frameborder = '0' "

`<iframe onload = " this.frameborder='0' "   src="menu.html"  id="menu"> </iframe>`

Or `getElementsByTagName]("iframe")`[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) adding this attribute for all iframes on the page?

Haven't tested this because I've done something which means that **nothing** is working in IE less than 9!
:)
So while I'm sorting that out ...  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice work around that will allow it to work in IE7 [here](https://sitevalidator.com/top100/errors/fix/the-frameborder-attribute-on-the-iframe-element-is-obsolete-use-css-instead). It bypasses the validator for the frameBorder attribute but keeps css for future browsers as explained in the post.

Comment: use JavaScript to generate the iframe? it will further defer the load time of iframe contents for just eliminating a CSS warning message. Like accepted answer says, recommended to use `seamless` attribute instead.

Comment: Yes, however seamless was not working for me in IE7 hence my post.