# HTML 5 compatible iFrame Attributes and older browsers (<IE8)

Tags: jquery, css, html, iframe

### Brief Explanation

I am aware that this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601273/html5-and-frameborder), however, that was 2 years ago and I am hoping there have been some updates since then.

As it states [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), many of the old attributes for `iFrames` are no longer supported in HTML 5. Instead, one must use CSS or the `seamless` tag to achieve what the no longer supported attributes enabled you to achieve.

The problems arise when you are trying to apply these affects to an older browser such as (dare I say it) Internet Explorer.

Consider this example:

```
<iframe src="//somepage" frameborder="0" scrolling="0"></iframe>
```

This will return a validation error on an HTML 5 document because both the `frameborder` and `scrolling` attributes are no longer supported in HTML 5. However, in `<IE8`, the CSS styles `border` and `overflow` have absolutely no effect on the `iFrame`.

### My Question

Is there a way of applying `frameborder="0" scrolling="0"` effects in all browsers whilst also avoiding validation errors?

*I would rather do this without using some sort of browser condition like:*

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    // Apply attributes here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: IE8 is in no way made to support HTML5. If you need IE8 support change to HTML4 or make a javascript solution that ships around this problem.

Comment: @SvenBieder I am well aware that IE8 does not support HTML5, that is why I am trying to find a workaround. I can very easily write a jQuery workaround but would rather not run a function on every page to check for iframes. I was hoping there might be something simpler, that is why I have asked this question

Comment: To my knowledge there is no easy 'just CSS' way up to now to use the HTML5 iframe attributes in IE8.

Comment: @SvenBieder Thank you, will resort to a Javascript workaround then :-)

Comment: You can just use the old attributes. It doesn't actually matter if you have a validation error.

Comment: @thirtydot Thats what I decided :-)

Comment: Just don't let the HTML5 police in when they come knocking :)

Comment: A wild try here, but have you tried using modernizr (http://modernizr.com/) in the [if lt IE 9] condition?