# seamless attribute not working html5

Tags: html, iframe

The seamless attribute doesn't seem to be working in my iframe but the frameborder is I am not sure why? I am working in html5. Even on the W3schools tutorial the seamless example still has a border so I am not sure what it is supposed to do. I thought that frameborder doesn't work in HTML5 so that is strange that it's working in mine.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Fly to the Limit</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/stylesheet.css">
   </head>

 <div class="mainInfo">
 <iframe seamless src="about.html" id="iframe" name="iframe" scrolling="no" 
 frameborder="0"></iframe> 
 </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 iframe seamless attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804604/html5-iframe-seamless-attribute)

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela yes but the post said that frameborder doesn't work in HTML5 and mine does.

Comment: I don’t know what post you are referring to, but “frameborder doesn't work in HTML5” just isn’t a meaningful statement. Things don’t work in HTML versions, they work in browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601273/html5-and-frameborder   "HTML 5 doesn't support attributes such as frameborder..."

Comment: the answer you are linking to cites Quackit.com, which is not an authoritative source and simply isn’t correct in this matter.

Comment: "The <iframe> frameborder attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_iframe_frameborder.asp