# iframe's frameborder attribute - html5

Tags: html, iframe, doctype

I am reading my HTML book and it states that iframe's scrolling and frameborder attributes are not supported in HTML5. The following code is declared in the book:

```
<iframe
    src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=moma+new+york&amp;output=embed"
    width="450"
    height="350"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

How comes the frameborder still works, if HTML5 does not support frameborder? If I don't put in that frameborder="0" line, the browsers load it with a frame around the image, while the frameborder="0" line takes out the frame. I thought this attribute is not supported in HTML5?

At the same time, scrolling seems to obey the rule of it not being supported in HTML5, as that line makes no difference at all (whether i set it to 0 or 1). The scrollbar is not shown either.

I am learning HTML at the moment, but this is so bizarre to me. Can someone help clarify this for me by any chance? I tested this in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: i tested it in both firefox and chrome

Comment: can you tell which ver?

Comment: if you are looking for how to do scrolling I think those two links might help ...let me know if it was helpful

Answer (score 5):

The book has got it wrong. Specifications (or, in this case, draft specifications) do not “support” elements or attributes; browsers do. Specifications *define* elements and attributes, and they present conformance clauses that say that conforming browsers must support elements and attributes so-and-so. This generally does not exclude the possibility that conforming browsers support other elements and attributes as well. Besides, browsers may be non-conforming; in fact, there is probably *no* browser that conforms to *any* HTML specification or draft, strictly speaking (though the conformance might be “good enough”).

In the case of `frameborder` and HTML5, the HTML5 Proposed Recommendation specifies that browsers are *expected* to support the attribute. Clause 10.4.3 [Attributes for embedded content and images](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#phrasing-content-0) says that certain CSS rules “ are expected to apply as presentational hints”, and they include the following:

```
iframe[frameborder=0], iframe[frameborder=no i] { border: none; }
```

This means that if an `iframe` element has the `frameborder` attribute with the value `0` or `no` (case insensitively), this corresponds to the CSS setting `border: none` on that element (defined to have specificity 0, so any explicit CSS setting of `border` on the element overrides it).

If this sounds odd, see section [Conformance requirements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#conformance-requirements). HTML5 has double standards, in the sense that it prohibits authors/document from using some constructs and yet requires or recommends browsers (and other user agents) to support them. So if you use `frameborder`, your document is non-conforming. Yet it is “expected” to be supported in a specific way.

The situation is in principle similar with the `scrolling` attribute. Its [expected effect](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-page) is that values `on`, `scroll`, and `yes` cause scrolling bars (like `overflow: scroll`), values `off`, `noscroll`, and `no` prevent scroll bars; and value `auto` causes scrollbars when content does not fit (the default). However, none of Firefox, Chrome, IE seems to support the values that cause scrolling bars unconditionally, and only Firefox supports all of the values that prevent them, whereas Chrome and IE support just `no`.

This is understandable in the sense that `scrolling=no` is the attribute that browsers have traditionally supported. The other values are more or less an invention in the HTML5 draft, probably supposed to cover some values actually in use or supported.

The bottom line with this is that `scrolling=no` works. To cause scrollbars even when not needed for the content, `scrolling=yes` is not useful in practice (the corresponding CSS setting works).

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation Jukka, I understand it more clearly now. So as the author of the code, the DOCTYPE declaration we state at the top simply states that our code is going to stick with the html5 standard (or try our best to) and if we do happen to make the mistake of not conforming 100% to it, then our code is nonconforming... but is there a penalty or effect that comes from having a nonconforming code to html5?

Comment: @JackJohnson, a doctype string affects only a) validation b) selection of standards vs. quirks mode. Nonconformance as such has no implications.

Comment: Question: so browsers; even if they are all the newest version, they all could have minor differences in terms of what what rules they choose to adopt right? while one might allow certain actions, it may not be so for another browser? eventhough both browser versions are up to date? is there a place to learn more about the differences between current browsers? and how do web developers account for all of these ? :\

Comment: @JackJohnson, yes, browsers have differences, even odd differences. There is no ultimate reference, but http://caniuse.com is often cited, for good reasons; but it focuses on support to modern features rather than legacy stuff. MDN is a great resource too, but e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe describes `scrolling` just as per HTML 4, and does not describe browser support.

Comment: got it. your answer makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

> The  frameborder attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS
>   instead.
>
> The frameborder attribute specifies whether or not to display a border
>   around an .
>
> Tip: It may be better to NOT specify a frameborder, and use CSS to
>   apply borders instead.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_frameborder.asp

[HTML5 and frameborder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601273/html5-and-frameborder)

[HTML5 : Iframe No scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470015/html5-iframe-no-scrolling)

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/2011/03/10/iframe-scrollbars-and-html5/

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: yeaa, your answer seems more reliable .... anyways I learn something new about frameborder here myself while trying to answer for him ...

Answer (score 0):

> How comes the frameborder still works, if HTML5 does not support frameborder?

Because HTML 4 defines `frameborder` and browsers haven't stopped supporting it.

You should still use CSS instead though.

Comment: Style elements don't belong mixed in with the markup. In the long run, they are harder to maintain than separate stylesheets.

Comment: ya i understand that styles should be done in css. regarding the question though... i thought if i declare my code as html5, then the browser will only apply the html5 rules to it :\ also, if browser still supports html4 and that's the reason frameborder still works, how come scrolling doesn't though. so weird.