# "The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead."

Tags: html, iframe, w3c-validation

I'm trying to validate my website with the W3C validator but it doesn't work. I have a YouTube iframe and this is the error:

> The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Screenshot:

[image]

And this is my index.html (cropped):

```
<!-- Video -->
<div class="video-container box-size">
  <iframe width="700" height="312" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OfUPsnAtZMI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 and frameborder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601273/html5-and-frameborder)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As they state themselves "The  frameborder attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."

The equivalent of frameborder in css is `border: 0px;`. Add it to your iframe in css.

Comment: according to answer for [question] 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601273/html5-and-frameborder)
you can replace `frameborder` in css with `border: none;`

Comment: Furthermore, `border: 0px` should otherwise be `border: 0`

Comment: "should" is not true. It could be `border: 0`, but `border: 0px` is [perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16484713/735926).

Answer (score 18):

Your HTML5 markup contains an `<iframe>` element with a frameborder attribute in the form:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" … />
```

This attribute is no longer present in HTML5. Use CSS instead:

```
<iframe style="border:0;" … />
```

Source: [Frameborder is obsolete](http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/the-x-attribute-on-the-y-element-is-obsolete-use-css-instead/the-frameborder-attribute-on-the-iframe-element-is-obsolete-use-css-instead/)

Comment: That's what the accepted answer, given two years ago, says.

Comment: True, but this way of writing the answer was really easy to see "take X...write Y instead"  Thanks to all!

Comment: @MichaelScottAsatoCuthbert in this case one should edit the existing answer, not duplicate it.

Answer (score 10):

This works in your css

```
iframe{
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the edge is held

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hidden` as `border-style` or `none`.

I made this to show the difference:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("submit");
const hidden = document.getElementById("hidden");
const none = document.getElementById("none");
const solid = document.getElementById("solid");
const iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
const error = document.getElementById("error")
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (hidden.checked) {
    iframe.style.borderStyle = "hidden";
  } else if (none.checked) {
    iframe.style.borderStyle = "none";
  } else if (solid.checked) {
    iframe.style.borderStyle = "solid";
  } else {
    error.textContent = "Choose the border then click Apply";
    setTimeout(function(){ error.textContent = "" },1000);
  }
});
```

```css
#iframe {
  border-style:solid;
}
#error {
color:red;
font-size:larger;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <iframe id="iframe" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="mode" id="hidden"><label for="hidden">Hidden border</label>
  <input type="radio" name="mode" id="none"><label for="none">No border</label>
  <input type="radio" name="mode" id="solid"><label for="solid">Solid border</label>
  <br />
  <button id="submit">Apply</button>
  <div id="error">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a manual workaround which is to remove the frameborder="0" attribute by adding the code in the post admin.

```
   <iframe title="K8 ký kết hợp đồng chính thức với Manchester City" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mNBbhn_pJik?feature=oembed" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

[remove frameborder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23YML.png)