# Replacement for hx (h1,h2,h3,etc)

Tags: html, css

Using the validator.w3 shows me the next error:

> Error: The element h3 must not appear as a descendant of the address element.

And also this other error:

> Error: The `frameborder` attribute on the `iframe` element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

So, my question is: how can I replace the `h3` inside the `address` tag? which is the tag to use? and then, how can I fix the `iframe error?

The code is:

```
<section id="Contacto">
    <div>
        <h2 class="concon">Contacto</h2>
        <div class="grupo-columnas centrar-columnas">
            <div class="columna">
                <address>
                    <h3>Mail</h3>
                    <a href="mailto:info@hyperx.com.ar" class="edit">info@hyperx.com.ar</a>
                    <h3>Llamanos</h3>
                    <a href="tel:540111122669288" class="edit">+54 011 2266-9288</a>
                    <h3>Ubicación</h3>
                    <p>Galería Jardín, Florida 537, Local 403, 1049 Buenos Aires</p>
                </address>
                <iframe id="mapa" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d5523.179529963751!2d-58.37788072464045!3d-34.6015771771587!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x95bccb43fa34ea69%3A0x9a4a3f10bd59e3e!2sFullh4rd!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sar!4v1591886402346!5m2!1ses-419!2sar" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: There are a variety of tags you can use inside the address tag, like `<span>`, `<p>`, and `<div>`. Just style them as needed

Answer (score 1):

> Error: The element h3 must not appear as a descendant of the address element.

Use a [text element](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp) like `<em>`, `<span>` or `<p>`. Apply any needed styling to that element to get the desired result

> Error: The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Remove the `frameborder="0"` from the `<iframe>` and apply some css to get the same result: `iframe { border: none }`.

Apparently, this has already been answered on StackOverflow: ["The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274082/the-frameborder-attribute-on-the-iframe-element-is-obsolete-use-css-instead)