# Iframe with no border?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove border from IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034/remove-border-from-iframe)

I started on a website project some weeks ago, and needed some help,
I have this iframe code for PHP, but i want it to show no border, how do i do that?

heres the code `<iframe src="http://localhost/jesper/nyhedder.php"></iframe>`

And i wanted to make the border = 0, instead of it showing inside an table. It is very anoying that it's showing in a Table, i could also make it PHP, but the PHP won't show up because i put the PHP code inside some HTML Code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034/remove-border-from-iframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing to do with php here. simply use CSS:

```
iframe
{
    border: 0;
}
```

or add `frameborder="0"` to `<iframe>`

Comment: @TommyMilboGrundstad If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept this answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

On the iframe tag add the attribute frameborder='0'. here is a exmple.

```
<iframe width="600" scrolling="no" height="700" frameborder="0" style="width: 600px; height: 280px;" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

just use css man!

```
iframe {
    border: none;
}
```