# Mystery border around table

Tags: html, css, iframe, border, html-table

As the title says, I have this small border around the entire table. I've just copied it from J2Ski to use on my website so it's not my own work.

I know this has most definitely been answered before but I can't figure out where to place the style in it and I'm not too sure what to place in there anyway.

```
<table style="border:none;">
<tbody>
<tr><td>
<iframe height="112" src="http://www.j2ski.com/snow_forecast/France/Tignes_mini.html"
width="340"></iframe>
</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NGn9Y/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's `iframe` border and not the `table` `border`, so use `frameBorder="0"` for your `iframe` element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NGn9Y/4/)

> Note: IE requires capital `B` for `frameBorder` so make sure you don't
>   write <s>`frameborder="0"`</s>

---

Also, there is no harm in writing the below snippet in your CSS as [@BeNdErR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702425/1542290) suggested, but that fails in older versions of IE, so also declare the `attribute` along with the below snippet in your CSS

```
iframe {
   border: 0;
}
```

Comment: IE actually never required `frameBorder` with a capital B. I don't know where that story came from. It was always case insensitive! Only the corresponding JavaScript property has a capital B.

Answer (score 1):

that is the `iframe` border

**CSS**

```
iframe{
    border: none;
}
```

also, have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034/remove-border-from-iframe) other question about `iframe border`

Comment: This will fail in older versions of IE if am not mistaken

Comment: I think you're right, updated with a link on a specific discussion.