# Can't Remove Border on iFrame embedded video

Tags: css, iframe, video, responsive-design

Having an issue removing a border on an embedded video (via Wistia) using iFrame. The page is at http://autopilotlist.wpengine.com/3-listing-leads-t/.

I'm examined the css using "inspect element" in chrome, and have confirmed that the border isn't a css issue (as best I can tell). Curiously, the border only appears on the top and left edges - which makes it almost look like a shadow or something.

I've also confirmed that the aspect ratio of the rendered video is an exact 16:9, so I don't believe the issue is from a resizing issue.

This is driving me nuts that I can't get rid of the border. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Edited: the frameBorder attribute is set:

```
<iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/tyxdpoy7rw?videoFoam=true" autoplay="true"     playbar="false" controlsVisibleOnLoad="false" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="960"></iframe><script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/iframe-api-v1.js"></script>
```

And the seamless='seamless' attribute didn't work for me.

Thanks to @marc-audet - The movie file was the problem. I created the video using 1920x1080 .png images. For some reason the file rendered with a border on the top and the left. I scaled the clips to be 101% and centered the images. When I re-rendered and uploaded to Wistia, the new embedded movie is beautifully borderless. Thanks so much for the tip, I would have never tried that otherwise!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_frameborder.asp

Comment: Sorry, I forgot ask you if there is some reason to use css instead of atribute?

Comment: The border may be part of the video itself, in which case, you would need to edit the video (Flash file?) if you have access to the original source.

Comment: Good idea, but the embed code already has the frameborder attribute set: <iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/tyxdpoy7rw?videoFoam=true" autoplay="true" playbar="false" controlsVisibleOnLoad="false" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="960"></iframe><script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/iframe-api-v1.js"></script>

Comment: You are right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034/remove-border-from-iframe
Here David Basarab says, that you need to use frameBorder cause of IE. Note capital B. And this is the way seamless='seamless'

Comment: Marc Audet, I created the file in Final Cut Pro X and used Compressor for the final output. Neither of which would have added a border. That's a good thought though... I'm going to create a temp movie file and ensure the clips have a "full bleed" and test it.

Comment: user3424754, I've already tried seamless='seamless' and the case-sensitive version of frameBorder. No luck.

Comment: @marc-audet, winner winner, chicken dinner. The movie file was the problem. I created the video using 1920x1080 .png images. For some reason the file rendered with a border on the top and the left. I scaled the clips to be 101% and centered the images. When I re-rendered and uploaded to Wistia, the new embedded movie is beautifully borderless. Thanks so much for the tip, I would have never tried that otherwise!