# Remove border and background from iframe - Angular

Tags: css, angular, iframe, sass

I'm working in an Angular 8 project.
I have an iframe. it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see there is a black "border" around the document. I say "border" because it might actually just be the black background the iframe shows the document on top of.
I want to remove this black bordering, to get a result that'll be more like this (basically I want a seamless sort of style for the iframe):
[image]

I've read through the answers regarding [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034/remove-border-from-iframe), but none of them seem to work, and most of the answers are years old.`frameBorder` doesn't work because it's deprecated. Setting the style of the iframe to have no border doesn't remove the black lining. I also tried to set the background color to not be black but that also didn't work. `seamless` is also deprecated.

How can I remove this black lining?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here's some code if it helps, but it's just an iframe.

```
<iframe [src]="myURL">
    Sorry your browser does not support inline frames
</iframe>
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: @Aravind I've added the code to the question, but it's simply an iframe.